# How to optimize webpack/es6 overhead?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I've been optimizing the load time of my app and after some quick wins with optimizing my code I've noticed there seems to be a 500ms long intialization phase where all the require statements seems to be resolved, or something.

Can this be optimized and how?

I am using webpack, react and couple dozens of npm packages. 
The result file is 2.8M unzipped and around 900k zipped. There is not a huge amount of code of the app itself, its mostly npm packages.

I wonder if I can just compile this differently to avoid all the requires and what not in real time.

Update: I am using production build with dedupe plugin currently.

[image: Webpack/es6 overhead]

Comment: Have you tried `npm dedupe`? Has it shown any progress?

Comment: Great, tip! I've seen some overall reduction in the load time, but I still see that 500ms webpack_require chunk.

Comment: If you don't do much chunking (it looks like you don't), you probably should [go chunks](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) and improve start time by lazy-loading some of them. I don't think that something can be suggested without knowing more on your build. You can browse through profile and analyse which modules costly `__webpack_require__`s belong to. Check also [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/690).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll most likely do some splitting as that seems to be the only way to tackle this.

Comment: When looking at the profiler, make sure you differentiate between own/self time and total time. The total time spent in `__webpack_require__` is high, because running the module counts against the *total* time metric, but self time should be much lower (time spent in the function but not children).

Comment: By zipped you mean gzipped or minified? Is your file sizes are with source maps or not?

Comment: Both, without source maps.

Comment: Are you sure that you show us timeline of minify code? `__webpack_require__` in timeline says something different

Answer (score 3):

As some comments have already pointed out, we have to differentiate between build- and run-time. The [referenced guide](http://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html) from the webpack docs is about **build performance**.

While not using devtools like source maps and minifying code has impacts on the execution speed, I think the most important one is **chunking/lazy loading** (as [estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus) has already pointed out).

You should decide which parts of your application are not needed for the initial render. These parts should be moved into another chunk and loaded lazily via `require.ensure()`.

Usually your router is a typical place to load stuff asynchronously:

```
<Router>
    <Route
        path="/dashboard"
        getComponent={loadPage("Dashboard")}
    />
</Router>

function loadPage(page) {
    return (location, cb) => pages[page](cb);
}

const pages = {
    Dashboard(cb) {
        require.ensure(
            ["./Dashboard.js"],
            require => cb(null, require("./Dashboard.js").default)
            // .default is required in case you are using ES2015 modules
        );
    }
};
```

Now, all modules that are only needed on the `Dashboard` will be moved into a separate chunk.

The verbose `require.ensure` part can even be optimized by moving all top-level components (I call them `pages` here) into a dedicated folder like `pages`. Then you can configure webpack to always load these things asynchronously by using the [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader):

```
// webpack.config.js
...
{
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve("path", "to", "pages"),
    ],
    loaders: [
        "bundle-loader?" + JSON.stringify({
            lazy: true
        })
    ]
},
```

Then your router looks like:

```
// This does not actually import the Dashboard,
// but a function which loads the dashboard.
import Dashboard from "path/to/pages/Dashboard";

function loadPage(page) {
    return (location, cb) => pages[page](module => {
        cb(null, module.default);
    });
}

const pages = {
    Dashboard
};
```

And if you're super-lazy and you only want to refer to the same filename without creating a `pages`-Object manually, you can also use [require contexts](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html):

```
function loadPage(page) {
    return (location, cb) =>
        require("./path/to/pages/" + page + ".jsx")(
            module => cb(null, module.default)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is to play around with the [devTool config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) and change the way you generate your sourcemaps. That should speed things up a bit at the expense of ease of debugging.

Webpack actually has a great little guide on how to optimise performance here http://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html.

Basically it boils down to how much debugging information you feel you need.

By setting

```
{
  devtool: "#source-map"
}
```

You preserve the original code, which is obviously the easiest to debug, but this comes at the expense of files size / build time.

**Updated:**
As per Chris' comment below, here is [another guide](http://moduscreate.com/optimizing-react-es6-webpack-production-build/)

Comment: Great answer! This [guide](http://moduscreate.com/optimizing-react-es6-webpack-production-build/) might complement it well.

Comment: Chris !== Chris. I was under impression that the question concerns runtime performance and not build time, so this is all about chunking and lazy loading.

Comment: @estus i could be very wrong, but runtime performance does involve rebuilding / compiling the app on save / content change. Where it hangs on the `require` statements could be due to webpack trying to sourcemap the modules?

Comment: I believe that the OP shows performance graph on page loading, so this is about *app* runtime performance, not *builder* runtime performance.

Comment: Chris 2.0 here. I do get (slightly) better performance on a production build compared to a development one.

Comment: I am using production built already so the graph is from a production build.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that your timeline comes from minify code (compare `__webpack_require__` in maped files and `f` in minify code).

I will show that minify and some plugins can reduce two times running time of this script. In webpack configs I will show only the main difference between to configurations.

---

### Develop mode

`webpack.config.js`

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
cache: true,
debug: true,
```

**Timeline - 473 ms**

[image: timeline in develop mode]

### Production mode

`webpack.config.js`

```
plugins: [
    'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
    'transform-react-constant-elements',
    'transform-react-inline-elements'
],
cache: false,
debug: false,
plugins: [
    // Search for equal or similar files and deduplicate them in the output
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

    // Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks
    // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            screw_ie8: true, 
            warnings: false,
        },
    }),

    // A plugin for a more aggressive chunk merging strategy
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-   plugins.html#aggressivemergingplugin
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
]
```

**Timeline - 228 ms**

[image: timeline in production mode]

---

If you would like to analize in depth `webpack.config.js` from this explanation you can take a look at source code from [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js).

Comment: Hi, true - I noticed it as well. Thanks for showing how much time is saved in just doing minification! I'll go over your config and see what I can apply as well.